# MVVM Light execute method in external library

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I try to execute a method in an external library:

This is the interface of the external library:

```
public interface IExternal
{
    string Name { get; }
    Task DoAsync();
}
```

This is the class of the external library:

```
public class ExternalClass : IExternal
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Test external";
        }
    }

    public async Task DoAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do async");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done async");
    }
}
```

This is the local class my ViewModel uses:

```
public class External
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand Run { get; set; }
}
```

In my application i load the external library as an reference.
An try to bind DoAsync as RelayCommand:

```
foreach (var item in externals)
{
    var t = new External();
    t.Name = item.Name;
    t.Description = "test";
    t.Run = new RelayCommand(async () => await item.DoAsync());
}
```

The XAML binding of the button is as follows:  Command="{Binding Run}"

Nothing happens, no command is executed.

Comment: Are there any binding errors in output window? Show relevant XAML, please. Also note, that you can pass `item.DoAsync` directly instead of creating additional delegate: `new RelayCommand(item.DoAsync)`.

Comment: Make sure you have no binding error. Check if with snoop or in output. The fact that your code is calling an external library doen't change anything, so you are looking in wrong direction.

Comment: There are no binding erros. If i bind a local method `void TestMethod() {..}` it just work fine.

Comment: I guess the binding cannot work because your reference is incomplete. Maybe try following: Command="{Binding External.Run}"